# GACK Response Closing a Case and get an Unknown Exception Code

Tags: exception, unexpectedexception

We are trying to close a case that was reopened and then when we go to close it again, we get the following error message. We recently went through the Spring Update 2023 and wondering if there is a way to track this down. A support ticket was also submitted to Salesforce.

Not writing any code but feel this is something related to code that is not compatible with Salesforce Spring Update and would like to solve this before more cases cannot be closed.

UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1201388981-36319 (-1557933027)

Comment: While there are a few Salesforce employees floating around here, most of us are just users/customers of Salesforce like yourself. We can't do anything with these "GACK" error codes. If you have a support plan, then (as unpleasant as SFDC's support process is) you should raise a case through https://help.salesforce.com

Comment: did you turn debug on and look at the log? - the error could be in a Flow or some other automation

Comment: Thanks for the responses. We had opened a SFDC. Take care,